# Is there a way to merge two dataframes and only keep a certain number of occurrences?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

For example. If I have two datasets:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2.1, 5, 0, 'a'], [7, 2.3, 5, 1, 'b'], [0, 2, 0, 1, 'c'], [9, 4, 4, 1, 'd']],columns=list('ABCDE'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 2, 5, 0, 1, 2], [3, 2.4, 5, 1, 9, 9], [9, 9, 5, 9, 4, 5], [0, 2, 5, 0, 1, 1], [1, 4, 4, 3, 8, 0]],columns=list('xBCyzw'))
```

and I want to merge them based just on columns 'B' and 'C', but I only want there to be as many instances of the merged rows as there were in df1.

**In other words, I want to find rows in df2 that match rows in df1 based on 'B' and 'C' and append the columns from df2 to df1.**

What I have right now is

```
print(pd.merge(np.round(df2), np.round(df1), on=['B', 'C'], how='inner', left_index = True))
```

which outputs

```
   x    B  C  y  z  w  A  D  E
0  3  2.0  5  0  1  2  1  0  a
1  3  2.0  5  0  1  2  7  1  b
0  3  2.0  5  1  9  9  1  0  a
1  3  2.0  5  1  9  9  7  1  b
0  0  2.0  5  0  1  1  1  0  a
1  0  2.0  5  0  1  1  7  1  b
3  1  4.0  4  3  8  0  9  1  d
```

but since there was only two rows with B=2, C=5 in df1, I want there to also just be two in the merged result. It doesn't matter which of the three matching rows in df2 get merged.

example:

```
   x    B  C  y  z  w  A  D  E
0  3  2.0  5  0  1  2  1  0  a
1  3  2.0  5  0  1  2  7  1  b
3  1  4.0  4  3  8  0  9  1  d
```

or:

```
   x    B  C  y  z  w  A  D  E
0  3  2.0  5  1  9  9  1  0  a
1  3  2.0  5  1  9  9  7  1  b
3  1  4.0  4  3  8  0  9  1  d
```

or:

```
   x    B  C  y  z  w  A  D  E
0  0  2.0  5  0  1  1  1  0  a
1  0  2.0  5  0  1  1  7  1  b
3  1  4.0  4  3  8  0  9  1  d
```

I can't think of a better way to do it other than a loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: You've only changed the output. not the input that produces it. Some expected result would also help

Comment: sorry, i'm trying to explain it without confusing myself and everyone who's trying to help X.X

Comment: I cannot reproduce your current result based on this code and input.

Comment: please try again, i re - copy pasted the df's

Comment: Check my answer now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, round `df1` and `df2`:

```
i, j = map(np.round, [df1, df2])
```

Next, merge on `B` and `C`:

```
v = pd.merge(i, j, on=['B', 'C'], how='inner', left_index=True)
```

Add dummy count columns to `i` and the merged result:

```
v['Count'] = v.groupby(['B', 'C']).cumcount()
i['Count'] = i.groupby(['B', 'C']).cumcount()
```

Perform a second merge on `i` with the new count column.

```
v.merge(i[['B','C','Count']], on=['B','C','Count']).drop('Count', 1)

   A    B  C  D  E  x  y  z  w
0  1  2.0  5  0  a  3  0  1  2
1  1  2.0  5  0  a  3  1  9  9
2  9  4.0  4  1  d  1  3  8  0
```